# play back song in iPhoneapp

Tags: iphone

I want to play a song global in iPhone. If I quit the sound application and I dont pause the song then that song play globle in iphone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is possible since iOS 4 which allows you to perform some tasks in the background. Luckily playing audo is one of them. You need to read the [Executing Code in the Background guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/prerelease/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH5-SW4) from Apple.

To break it down for you, first you need to see if your device supports multitasking:

```
UIDevice* device = [UIDevice currentDevice];
BOOL backgroundSupported = NO;
if ([device respondsToSelector:@selector(isMultitaskingSupported)])
   backgroundSupported = device.multitaskingSupported;
```

Then you need to edit your plist to declare that you are taking advantage of background tasks. You use `UIBackgroundModes` which takes an array of values, but you only need `audio`.

Then the actual coding, see [Initiating Background Tasks](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/prerelease/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH5-SW6).

Comment: sir how can i do audio streaming with play audio in the background in iphone

Comment: @sidhu - You should create a new question for your new question :)

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, it is possible. In the iOS4, you can [play audio in the background](http://developer.apple.com/technologies/ios/whats-new.html)